# How can a d-app gain users' trust?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

As a developer developing a decentralized app, for example, this app will hold users' digital assets. What are the ways to make this app trustworthy?

Answer (score 0):

The term "trustless" can be misleading and unhelpful, as it suggests that trust is entirely eliminated. In reality, users are still required to trust in something new that the app designer or founder has created. The key is to design something that is trustworthy and transparent, while addressing possible sources of distrust.

One way to create trust is to automate the contract completely, with no possibility of change to the code or intervention by an outside authority. However, this requires users to trust in the infallibility of the algorithm, the enduring perfection of the code, and the Ethereum network's continued correct operation. Therefore, it's crucial to ensure the code is immaculate, respects best practices, and has been thoroughly audited by a reputable specialist.

To minimize the possibility of abuse of privilege, contracts should constrain the owner's actions, and unnecessary privileges should be designed away to create the minimum viable administrative controls. Even with these constraints, users will still need to trust the owner to do their job and never misuse their privilege. Therefore, it's essential to choose a trustworthy organization as the owner and create a governance structure to ensure accountability.

A multi-signature wallet with publicly disclosed signers and a contract that limits their actions can serve as a general template. It's also essential to have a strategy for key management and be prepared to defend it.

In summary, the goal is to design a trustworthy system while addressing potential sources of distrust. This involves creating transparent processes, minimizing privileges, and ensuring accountability.